# What to do about those Shutdown Errors?

Tags: 12.10, ati, cinnamon

When I press shutdown it goes to this screen:

```
mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth
acpid : exiting
[1078.933492] INFO: task Xorg :1128 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[1078.933628] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[1078.933492] INFO: task Xorg :1128 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[1078.933628] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[1078.933492] INFO: task Xorg :1128 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[1078.933628] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

and hasn't turned off 10 minutes later.

Running 12.10 with cinnamon DE, AMD HD3000 graphics, /home partition on different drive and conky setup. Any ideas?

Comment: Same error onUbuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` what's hapenning.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0ByqC3qYEgxFPeFpSdFdlYUc2R1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The only interesting part I found is in the Xorg when it complains about the fglrx driver: `Failed to load module "fglrx"'`.

Maybe this is the right direction, who knows..:-(

Another one in syslog:
`Mar 16 17:49:35 corey-desktop kernel: [   14.984817] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000b00-0x0000000000000b07 SystemIO conflicts with Region \SOR1 1 (20120320/utaddress-251)`

Comment: One link that suggest how to WORKAROUND the problem (simply making the timeout=0 permanent):
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/kernel-error-echo-0-proc-sys-kernel-hung-_task_timeout_secsin-redhat-5-8-a-4175432693/

And one older:[http://freejabber.com/2011/11/02/amd-ati-radeon-driver-hangs-and-freezes-on-ubuntu-11-04/